# How to color cells using the flextable R package based on their values when there are missing values?

Tags: r, flextable

I'm trying to produce a flextable that intentionally has missing/blank values. However, when I try to add conditional formatting to the table (e.g., color cells based on their value), I receive the following error:

```
"Error in data_colors(source_dataset, color) : colors can not contain missing values."
```

I understand that the missing values are driving the error, but I'm not sure how to adjust the function or code in order to work around the problem.

Here is an example using the Iris dataset. I first apply the conditional color formatting on a clean dataset without NA's. That code works correctly.

I then intentionally introduce an NA into the dataset, run the code again, and receive the error above.

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

# function to return "red" if value is between four and five
my_color_fun <- function(x) {
  if_else(x > 4 & x < 5, "red", "black")
}

df <- iris

# color flextable on clean dataset
flextable(df) %>%
  color(j = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"), color = my_color_fun)
  
# introduce NA into dataset
df$Sepal.Length[5] <- NA

# color flextable on dataset with NA
flextable(df) %>%
  color(j = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"), color = my_color_fun)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `NA` is not printed when generating the table via flextable, it is not possible to color the NA as it is not printed. Hence we need to used the background to color the missing values as below

```r
# color flextable on dataset with NA
flextable(df) %>% bg(i = ~ is.na(Sepal.Length), 
                     j = ~ Sepal.Length, 
                     bg="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need to adjust the cell colors and not the background. If it can't be done by adjusting the function, perhaps I will just need to coerce NAs into a string so that they have a value and then apply color formatting (e.g., white) to match the background.

Comment: yes , that approach will work